# Teams 'navigator.permissions' is 'undefined' in Tabs/Task on Mobile devices

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/browser-device-permissions) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile) articles we are implementing device permissions for our Tab/Task web apps, to prepare it for the next Teams update (February 01, 2022).

And we have an issue on the 'Check permissions from your app' step.
The example in the article says we should use HTML5 permissions API to check permissions:

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'camera' });
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' });
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' });
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'notifications' });
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'midi', sysex: true });
```

But the problem is that this API only works in Web/Desktop apps and not on mobile.
On Mobile devices we see this error:

[image]

It seems like there is no way to check permissions without causing a prompt if we can't use HTML5 permissions API. Teams API doesn't give us such functionality as well.

Is this expected or can this be considered as a bug ?
Any help would be appreciated.

The app versions are:

`Android: 1416/1.0.0.2021183702/1117`

`IOS: 3.20.77.2021202701/1121 (general)`

**Developer preview** is **turned on** on both mobile devices.

Comment: To get the device permissions for mobile, please go through this section [Use Teams APIs to get device permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile#use-teams-apis-to-get-device-permissions)

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Nope. The idea behind using 'navigator.permissions.query' is to check whether permissions were granted without actually requesting permissions. Without this functionality there's no way of getting that information without invoking a prompt window. We did workaround but this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT is this issue still open..? I'm facing a similar issue too..?

Comment: @Oleksa Whats the work around you did..?

Comment: @Raghavendra - We are actively checking the updates on this bug with engineering team and let you know the updates, if any.

Comment: Engineering team has confirmed that this API isn't supported on Android WebView.